# Angular Can't resolve all parameters for SomeEffect (?)

Tags: angular, angular6, ngrx, ngrx-effects

i am having an issue with "ngrx/effects" library where it cannot resolve the parameter(s) given to the effect class below...

some.effect.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Action } from '@ngrx/store';
import { Effect, Actions } from '@ngrx/effects';

@Injectable()
export class SomeEffect {

   constructor( private actions$: Actions ) { }

   @Effect()
   someAction: Observable<Action> = this.actions$.ofType
   ...
}
```

app.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        StoreModule.forRoot(reducers, {metaReducers}),
        EffectsModule.forRoot([SomeEffect])
    ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

produces the error ...

> Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for SomeEffect: (?).

Has anyone come into this issue before?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Running the Angular CLI as --AOT solved this issue.

Answer (score 1):

change `start` in your package.json from `ng serve` to `ng serve --aot`.